# Is this set up to measure CMRR correct?

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, integrated-circuit, simulation, cmrr

Is this set up to measure CMRR correct? 
 Why did he not consider \$V_{out}/2\$ in his derivation?
Also is there any reason to use plus-minus sign `±` for the gain? 
Link: [page 5/13](http://pallen.ece.gatech.edu/Academic/ECE_6412/Spring_2003/L240-Sim&MeasofOpAmps(2UP).pdf)
[image]

Comment: Did you see this?  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/432511/why-is-cmrr-effect-multiplied-by-gain-in-this-non-inverting-op-amp-configuration/432530#432530  or this https://forum.allaboutcircuits.com/threads/common-mode-voltage-for-op-amp.156819/#post-1361227

Comment: Would that configuration also be used to measure CMRR? 
Btw, I checked the author's book and the derived it with Av + Acm/2 in the denominator and because Acm/2 << Av so it's ignored.

Comment: Yes, you can use this circuit to measure the CMRR.